# Define variables vs. template

Tags: c++, qt, templates, struct, constants

In a project, we are creating files to be able to switch languages, during run-time, between English and French.

What are the pros and cons to using defines versus template of constant variables.

```
#define TRAINABLE_LABEL "Trainable:"
#define TRAINABLE_ONE "Easily trainable"
#define TRAINABLE_TWO "Moderately trainable"
#define TRAINABLE_THREE "Highly trainable"
```

In template:

```
const QString TRAINABLE_LABEL = "Trainable:"
const QString TRAINABLE_ONE = "Easily trainable";
const QString TRAINABLE_TWO = "Moderately trainable";
const QString TRAINABLE_THREE = "Highly trainable";
```

Comment: Before you go too far, see what your development offers for internationalization support. You can likely avoid this entirely.

Comment: Hard to say. Could be because avoiding the use of macros as constants in modern C++ is extremely well documented. Often when a question is downvoted the downvoter also votes to close and some hints can be taken from that, but not this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: why do you call it templates?

With a a simple `#define` you are not really protected against redefition of a certain macro, typeness, etc. So macros for these things should be avoided.

Best way would probably be to use `constexpr char*`. This gives you the same behaviour as a macro and will issue an error when some variable is redefined.